# CoverFlow using UIVIews

Tags: iphone, uiview, coverflow

I am trying to implement "CoverFlow" in iPhone referring http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m . But what I actually want is a coverflow of UIViews, and not images. ie, I want my coverflow to contain controls like UIViews and not static images. Is this possible ? Please help ... Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this library does exactly that.

http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/